# Visualization of an algebraic stack

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks, visualization, geometric-intuition

*As the visuallization of an algebraic stack is virtually impossible I warn about this is a soft question*.

I am interested in thinking visually about algebraic stacks (also higher and derived stacks, but let´s start from the beginning) and I find quite suprising the fact that there isn´t a single "picture" of an algebraic stack in the literature. I would expect some analogue to [Mumford´s illustration of schemes](http://www.neverendingbooks.org/mumfords-treasure-map) for some example of algebraic stack but I cannot find it.

To be concrete, take  moduli stack of vector bundles $\mathcal{M}$ (of fixed rank and chern class)  on a scheme $S$. **How would you represent it graphically?**
The way I usually imagine $\mathcal{M}$ visually is that the fiber over a point of the base scheme  is not a single vector bundle but a set of vector bundles related by isomorphims.  However the condition that makes the stack to be algebraic (and consequently a *geometric space*) is roughly (for an Artin stack) that the diagonal is representable, quasi-compact and separated and that it has a smooth cover by an scheme (the atlas). Following  [T. Gomez "Introduction to Algebraic Stacks"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9911199.pdf)
[image: atlas of a stack]

I understand from this that if you have a family of isomorphic vector bundles $V_{ki}$ in each point $k$ (where $i=1,2,3,...$ denotes different isomorphic vector bundles over the same point $k$) the scheme $U$ is going to contain at least one  $V_{ki}$ for at least one value of $i$ in  each point of $U$

[image]

It would be great if someone can clarify this and specially to offer some way to imagine visually an algebraic stak (a picture itself would be even better!)

Comment: I do not know why do you think (or where it is mentioned) that $\mathcal{M}$ is parametrized by $U$... It only says that there exists a scheme $U$ and a morphism of stacks $U\rightarrow \mathcal{M}$, satisfying some properties... By Yoneda Lemma (I can say more here if you want), this morphism $U\rightarrow \mathcal{M}$ corresponds to the category $\mathcal{M}(U)$, which by definition is the collection of vector bundles over the scheme $U$...

Comment: Yes, I have misunderstood that. I have eliminated that part, the problem is to picture the stack; not that. What I wanted to say is that (to my understanding) $u$ is not really surjective but surjective up to isomorphism in the sense that you cannot obtain all the possible vector bundles moving along U; some of the different (although) isomorphic ones cannot be parameterized by U

Comment: I am trying to understand your question... Are you asking why $u:U\rightarrow \mathcal{M}$ is not considered to be surjective? I understand you want to visualize stack..

Comment: Ok. Really I am asking why $u$ is said to be surjective. I mean, I don´t understand in which sense $u$ is surjective as lot of objects of $\mathcal{M}$ cannot be obtained just moving along the scheme $U$.  I have also read that $U$ is a cover of $\mathcal{M}$  and I do not see why.

Comment: I understand that the name "surjective" is misleading... Actual name is "representable surjective (submersion)"... Experts use surjective to mean representable surjective (submersion)... It means, the map $u:U\rightarrow \mathcal{M}$ is such that, for any map $v:V\rightarrow \mathcal{M}$, the product $U\times_{\mathcal{M}}V$ is **representable** by a scheme and that the projection map $U\times_{\mathcal{M}}V\rightarrow V$ is **surjective (submersion)** of schemes... Does this partially answer your question?

Comment: Yes, that makes much more sense. Thanks!

Comment: :) :) Are there any other questions (other than visualization of stack)?

Comment: Not yet... I will probably re-edit the question a little to avoid mistakes, but as  I don´t see clearly a very better way to picture $\mathcal{M}$ I will wait if someone has any insight regarding to that. Thanks again.

Comment: I do not have hope for some one saying about picture of $\mathcal{M}$.. I will be more than happy to see if there is any.. :)

Comment: "Nice" stacks over an algebraically closed field $k$ are locally of the form $[X/G]$ for an affine scheme $X$ and a linearly reductive $k$-group scheme $G$: see https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.06467. You can picture this by drawing the $G$-orbits on $X$ and decorating points with the stabilizers.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik the question is about algebraic stacks, not differentiable stacks, and submersion is not a word you get to use here.

Comment: I would encourage thinking of algebraic stacks as being 'bad quotients' of schemes (ie that otherwise shouldn't exist), where the quotient is by an action that has stabilisers, but has otherwise mildly redeeming features.

Comment: @DavidRoberts That is correct, that is why I kept that word in brackets.. :) It is just for some motivation...